# Finding src from video tag in a div in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find the src of a video tag with BeautifulSoup in python

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = '<some url>'
client_id = {'Client-ID': '<some id>'}

json_data = requests.get(url, headers=client_id).json()

def download(some_url) :
    html_page = urlopen(some_url)
    soup = BS(html_page, "html.parser")

    link_to_vid = soup.find('video')['src']

    print(link_to_vid)

    # urllib.request.urlretrieve(video)


for x in range(0, num_clips):
    resp_url = (json_data['data'][x]['url'])
    print (resp_url)
    download(resp_url)
```

When running this script I get an output of

```
*link from print(resp_url)*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 28 in <module>
      download(resp_url)
  File "script.py", line 18 in download
      link_to_vid = soup.find('video')['src']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

It seems to me that this error is occurring because BeautifulSoup cannot find a video tag on the webpage. I tried printing the whole html page I got from BeautifulSoup and it looks like it doesn't get the whole webpage, at least not what I can see from Chrome devtools.

Am I getting this error because the video is nested deep within divs? Why isn't BeautifulSoup getting the whole html page?

Comment: it dynamic page, additional content added by javascript, use selenium.

Comment: As each URL usually requires different processing, the actual URL would be needed to help you.